# How can I rename a file in novell sever?

Tags: troubleshooting, rename, novell

My Server is using netware 4.X, I am one of their client. I can map the drive in F:\ for example, and I want to rename the file which is located in F:\ , but I get follow error:

> Duplicate file name or file in use.

I can ensure that I type the file name within duplicate. And I am the only client I connect to the server. How can I rename the file, or can I rename the file in Sever? (I have the right to access the Server directly.)

Answer (score 1):

I finally know what's happen. This is because the file is read ONLY. I use the "flag" cmd to change the file to read WRITE, after that, that's work.

Comment: Talking about confusing error messages...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean you have ssh access to the server.  If that is the case, use the mv command.

So if the current file is named file.ext, and you want it to be named file-bak.ext enter:

mv file.ext file-bak.ext

Comment: NetWare 4.x does not provide an SSH server by default. More, usually you "map" NetWare volumes not with SSH, but with a native NetWare client, produced by Novell or Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

Try co copy the file. If you can't, probably it's because you have a space in the filename.

-

There is a command that displays the files in use, but I can't remember it (it's in the manual for sure)